# AWS Aurora PostgreSQL - x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds

I have a (slight) working understanding of x509 certs and I've been trying to understand why the instructions I followed aren't working.

I followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html which simply says, connect with `sslmode=verify-ca` (or `verify-full`) and `sslrootcert=$CERTPATH`, where `$CERTPATH` is the path to cert they provide in the first paragraph of the guide. Doing that I get `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`.

Debugging this a bit, I (with my bad understanding of x509) expected the RDS to respond with some cert with `CN=*.something.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com` (the database) issued by something like `CN=Amazon RDS us-west-2 2019 CA` with an intermediate for chaining the `CN=Amazon RDS us-west-2 2019 CA` cert to `Amazon RDS Root 2019 CA` and `Amazon RDS Root 2019 CA` is our `sslrootcert`.

What I see is a cert with `CN=*.something.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com` issued by `OU=Server CA 1B, CN=Amazon` and an intermediate from `CN=Amazon,OU=Server CA 1B` to `Amazon Root CA 1` - Amazon's root cert on `amazontrust.com` from https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.pem. So `psql "postgres://.../dbname?sslmode=verify-ca&sslrootcert=AmazonRootCA1.pem"` works just fine.

Is Aurora misconfigured somehow? Am I doing something slightly wrong? I figure using `sslrootcert=AmazonRootCA1.pem` isn't terrible but I want to understand the piece I'm missing, mentally. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe related https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-rds-customers-update-your-ssl-tls-certificates-by-february-5-2020/

Comment: The database it failed on was created after the flip (by a CI run yesterday), so it should be ok, but I'll double check again.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the error with the below rds bundle from Aurora Doc:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html

But i tried other ca cert given in same wiki and it resolved "x509 unknown authority" issue and client is able to verify root cert.
https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2019-root.pem